# What filter should I use to insert a button inside on Media>Add New

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, hooks, media

I am adding a new way to upload a media file to WordPress. So I am looking for a way to add a link or a button to the Upload New Media page.

What is the recommended filter? Or is there another better solution to add a button?

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

I added a button named: "Other Option".

I also added: "Another option: Other Option". On top of Maximum upload file size...

Comment: Could you please elaborate where do you want button to go and what it should perform? Screenshot or mockup might be helpful in context of interface.

Comment: In Media>Add New you have a button in the middle of the screen "Select Files" is it possible to add a button next to it with WordPress? If it's javascript is it possible to add a link after: "Try the browser uploader instead."? Worst case I can do what @G. M. is proposing or even use JavaScript. But if I have to use JavaScript, where do I begin to add a button next to the "Select Files" button?

Comment: I did not give to many details because I though there was simple hooks (filters) that I could use but if @G. M. is right then I have to find another way. I am just trying to offer my users another way to get files to there WordPress... I am actually open to suggestions.

Comment: I misanderstand what you want to accomplish. Now looking at shortcode I've undestood, I'll try to answer this evening if no one have answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edited after OP insert edited question

---

Once you are creating a new upload system, I thing that you want to add button/link to different part of WP admin:

- A submenu on "Media" menu
- A submenu on the "New" menu in the Admin Bar
- A button inside the Media > Add New page (like in OP screenshot)
- A button near page title in the "Media Library" page

First 2 are pretty easy, thatnk to, respectively, [`add_media_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_media_page) and [`$wp_admin_bar->add_node`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_node) functions.

The third, is a bit hard to obtain, because thta button is hardcoded in core, it can be added via javascript, but in core there is an hook, [`'post-plupload-upload-ui'`](http://wpseek.com/hook/post-plupload-upload-ui/), that allow to output something after the dragging area, I think it can be good as well for your scope (see screenshot at bottom of this answer).

The fourth is the more hard to obtain, because there is no hook for that, however, just before the output of deafult "Add New" button, in the code there's this line:

```
echo esc_html( $title );
```

where `$title` is `__('Media Library')`.

The value returned by `esc_html` can be changed using the `esc_html` filter, so you can use this filter to output the markup of your custom buttom. However you should pay attention to run the filter only on proper page, only for the wanted string and remove it after first run: otherwise any string passed to `esc_html` will be affected.

Note that is a tricky way, so in future versions of WP it can't work anymore, but with current version (3.8) and previous (3.1 and newer) it works.

**I created a class, that handle all the 4 tasks**. The class is posted here as a standalone plugin, but probably it will be usefull to be integrated in your plugin.
Of course you have to customize the first 3 functions.

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Upload UI
 */
class CustomUploadUI {

  static function getLabel() {
    // change here the label of your custom upload button
    return 'Custom Add New Media';
  }

  static function getUrl() {
    // change here the url of your custom upload button
    return add_query_arg( array('page'=>'my-custom-upload'), admin_url('upload.php') );
  }

  function render() {
    // this is the function that render your custom upload system
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) {
      echo '<h2>Sorry, you are not allowed to upload files.</h2>';
      return;
    }
  ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <h2>Custom Upload System</h2>
    <p>Hi, I'm a custom upload system</p>
    <p class="submit"><input name="submit" onClick="alert('Foo!');return false;" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Upload Something" type="submit"></p>
    </div>
  <?php
  }

  function __construct() {
    add_action('load-upload.php', array($this, 'indexButton'));
    add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'submenu') );
    add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', array( $this, "adminBar" ) );
    add_action('post-plupload-upload-ui', array($this, 'mediaButton'));
  }

  function submenu() {
    add_media_page( self::getLabel(), self::getLabel(), 'upload_files', 'my-custom-upload', array($this, 'render') ); 
  }

  function adminBar() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) || ! is_admin_bar_showing() ) return;
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
      'parent' => 'new-content',
      'id' => 'custom-upload-link',
      'title' => self::getLabel(),
      'href' => self::getUrl()
    ) );
  }


  function mediaButton() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) {
      echo '<div><p align="center">';
      echo '<input id="custom-browse-button" type="button" value="' . self::getLabel() . '" class="button" />';
      echo '</p></div>';
      $this->mediaButtonScript();
    }
  }

  function mediaButtonScript() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) return;
  ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#custom-browse-button', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.location = '<?php echo self::getUrl(); ?>';
    });
    </script>
  <?php
  }

  function indexButton() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) return;
    add_filter( 'esc_html', array(__CLASS__, 'h2Button'), 999, 2 );
  }

  static function h2Button( $safe_text, $text ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'upload_files' ) ) return $safe_text;
    if ( $text === __('Media Library') && did_action( 'all_admin_notices' ) ) {
      remove_filter( 'esc_html', array(__CLASS__, 'h2Button'), 999, 2 );
      $format = ' <a href="%s" class="add-new-h2">%s</a>';
      $mybutton = sprintf($format, esc_url(self::getUrl()), esc_html(self::getLabel()) );
      $safe_text .= $mybutton;
    }
    return $safe_text;
  }

}

$ui = new CustomUploadUI;
```

---

### Screenshots

#### In the Media page

[image: Custom button add new media]

---

#### In the Media > Add New Page

[image: Custom button add new media]

---

#### New Submenu of Media Menu

[image: Custom button add new media]

---

#### New Submenu of "+ New" Menu in Admin Bar

[image: Custom button add new media]

Comment: Thank you very much! But can you also tell me what I can do to add to the menu on the left under Media "Custom Add New Media"?

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins I have completely edited my answer.

Comment: Wow! You're amazing! Thanks! I will check it out later today.

Comment: Amazing! I just copy and pasted. It worked just like that. Plug and play! Thank you very much. You sir deserve a beer! ;)